# How do I disable back button from the adapter to a fragment?

Tags: android

Please don't mark this as duplicate because the past questions weren't able to solve my problem.

I've already tried

```
@Override
onBackPressed(){
//do nothing
}
```

but it wasn't able to solve my problem.

My expectation for the output will be if the user pressed back, then he/she won't be able to do so since back pressed has been disabled and it should show a dialog box.

This is what I came up with, It's from an adapter:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Restart Progress");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to restart all the progress?");

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavDrawer.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog1 = alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog1.show();
}
```

While in my activity class is this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    weeklyExerciseAdapter2.onBackPressed();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: `onBackPressed` is a method of `activity` not `fragment`'s

Comment: Can you elaborate on the scenario you are using this code, normally you override it in the activity.

Comment: My bad, I want to use it in a fragment but I don't know how.

Comment: you mean if a certain fragment is visible then you wanted to disable backButton

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif exactly

Comment: in activity you are loading fragments with `viewPager` or `fragmentManager`

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif with **fragmentManager**

Comment: then in your activity override `onBackPressed` method like you done in question add a condition as mention `if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YOUR_BACK_BTN_DISABLE_FRAG_TAG") instanceof MYFragment){
}else {super.onBackPressed()
}

Comment: are you talking about android phone's back button or `toolBar`'s button because if you are taking about `toolbar`'s back button then the implementation is different

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif the phone's back button

Comment: then override `onBackPressed` in your **activity** must work until unless you have override `onKeyDown` method too

Comment: I'm using a fragment.

Comment: yes i know but you can control backButton event from your __activity__ and you are loading that fragment from you __activity__ too so override `onBackPressed` in your __activity__ check  whether your fragment is viewing if yes the disable backPress Event

Comment: is there some additional logic from fragment that also has effect over backButton

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I'm sorry. I'm trying it now.

Comment: no need to be sorry, if got issue in implementation you can ask

Comment: What I actually want to happen is that the `onBackpressed` is from adapter and when it is triggered then it should show a dialog.

Comment: I've edited the question with code.

Comment: you mean you want to open a dialog on backPress event or you want to trigger onBackPress from dialog which has been open from adapter within the fragment

Comment: I want to open a dialog `onBackPressed` is it doable?

Comment: so what i guess is when user click back button (when he/she was on a Specific Fragment) you want to open a dialog which is implemented in Adapter that is in that Specific Fragment is it true

Comment: yes it is true.

Comment: and your dialog ask user to start `NavDrawer` activity

Comment: now in your adapter code that open the dialog that you given in question has no conditional role of the adapter just opening a dialog regardless of anything in adapter, so there is no need of that code to be in adapter

Comment: if you still want to do this from fragment then i assume that you write a public method in your fragment named `onBackPressed` override `onBackPress` method in your __ACTIVITY__ check the condition for your desire Fragment (that i have given in the answer) if condition meets then call `((MYFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YOUR_BACK_BTN_DISABLE_FRAG_TAG")).onBackPressed()` now you get `onBackPressed` call in your desire fragment when user presses the BackButton (note that: this is not a good approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your **`activity`** override `onBackPressed` method like below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YOUR_BACK_BTN_DISABLE_FRAG_TAG") instanceof MYFragment){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed() 
    }
}
```

Comment: is there some additional logic from fragment that also has effect over backButton press event

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hacky solution but you could just clear the back stack.
If you are using fragment manager, try the following inside your fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
   for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
   fm.popBackStack();
}
```

or

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Both should work.

**Note**: This won't disable the back button, the user simply will not be able to go to the previous fragment.